# Use a namespace when referencing different files in JS

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to prefix more than one external file in JS when referencing to them with

```
///<reference path="..\..\IntelliSense Files\Order Form - Information.js"/>
```

?
I have different files with the same structure and I would like to use them from the same JS file.

Comment: What do you mean by "prefix an external file"? The file path is of no interest to the JS, you can modify it arbitrarily. However, all js will be executed in the same global scope, so if you worry about the objects created in there you will need to namespace them explicitly

Comment: They are dynamically created, so I cannot do that manually

Comment: Well, then you'd modify the dynamic creation process…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that cannot be done unless you create some dynamic `<script>` tags.

The `<reference>` tag only acts as a hint for Intellisense for showing up the autocomplete. It does nothing when deployed.